# validate selected dropdown value in gridview and populate label with selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to avoid duplicate selection of persons for the same room number and also populate label with selected person.PLease see jsfiddle for the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/bharatgillala/9o1gxa1h/4/

html

```
<table id="gridviewInfo" runatr="server">


 <TBODY><TR>
<TH scope=col>Available Person</TH>
 <TH scope=col>RooNumber</TH>
<TH scope=col>SelectedPerson</TH>

</TR>

<TR>
 <TD style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" align=left><SELECT    onchange=checkforvalue(this) id=ddlAvailableJudges name=ctl00$contentBody$gvwRoomInformation$ctl02$ddlAvailableJudges>

<OPTION selected value=>
</OPTION>
<OPTION  value=maxico>maxico
   </OPTION> <OPTION value=chennai>chennai</OPTION> <OPTION value=newdelhi>newdelhi</OPTION> <OPTION value=hongkong>hongkong</OPTION>    </SELECT> </TD>
 <TD style="WIDTH: 100px">1</TD>
<td>
<label > populate  </label>
</td>    
</TR>

<TR>
  <TD style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" align=left>

   <SELECT onchange=checkforvalue(this) id=ddlAvailableJudges name=ctl00$contentBody$gvwRoomInformation$ctl03$ddlAvailableJudges> 

    <OPTION selected value=>
  </OPTION>
    <OPTION  value=maxico>maxico</OPTION> <OPTION value=chennai>chennai</OPTION> <OPTION value=newdelhi>newdelhi</OPTION> <OPTION value=hongkong>hongkong</OPTION></SELECT> </TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 100px">2</TD>

  <td>
  <label > populate  </label>
   </td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the same ids for the dropdowns (IDs should be unique). Here is the code. I've added class names to dropdowns and given unique IDs to each dropdown.

Here is a [link to the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9o1gxa1h/6/)

```
    $('.judges').change(function(){
    //on change get selected dropdown's value
    var curVal = $('option:selected',this).val();
    //get the id of the dropdown changed
    var curId = this.id;
    //set the label with selected value
    $(this).parents().eq(1).find('td:nth-child(3) > label').html(this.value);
    //loop through all the dropdowns
    $('.judges').each(function() {
        //for each dropdown get the selected value
        var innerVal = $('option:selected',this).val();
        if(innerVal !== ''){
            //if id of the dropdown is different to that of the original dropdown selected & the selected values are the same clear the selection of the old dropdown
            if(innerVal === curVal && curId != this.id){
                $(this).val(" ");
                $(this).parents().eq(1).find('td:nth-child(3) > label').html('populate from selected');
            }
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents().eq(1).find('td:nth-child(3) > label').html('populate from selected');
        }
    });
});
```